# CSS not using nested className rules

Tags: javascript, html, css, reactjs, sass

Having an issue creating an accordion component. i have a collapsed state which gets passed as a className, if state is true, to a div tag. In the css, what's supposed to happen is that if collapsed className is true show content but what happens is that when button(that changes the state) is clicked, div gets 'collapsed' className but in the css, it doesn't use the $ .collapsed nested rules. Any help is appreciated. Not really good with css.

### ErrorNotification.js

```
import React, { Component } from 'react'
import { Typography, Button } from 'rmwc'
import { Icon } from 'rmwc/Icon'
import cn from 'classnames/bind'
import styles from './index.css'

const cx = cn.bind(styles)

export class ErrorNotification extends Component {
  state = {
    collapsed: true,
  }

  toggleAccordion = () => this.setState({ collapsed: 
    !this.state.collapsed
  })

  buttonIcon = 'keyboard_arrow_down'

  render() {
    console.log('collapsed', this.state.collapsed)
    return (
      <div className={cx('error-notification-container')}>
        <Typography className={cx('error-notification-message')}>There 
        was an error in retrieving the configuration data.</Typography>
        <div className={cx('accordion-container', { collapsed: 
        this.state.collapsed })}>
          <div className={cx('accordion-top-section')}>
            <Button className={cx('accordion-button')} onClick= 
              {this.toggleAccordion}>
              <Icon strategy="ligature">{this.buttonIcon}</Icon>
            </Button>
          </div>
          <div className={cx('accordion-panel')}>
            <Typography>
              Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, 
              sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore 
              magna aliqua.
            </Typography>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    )
  }
}
```

### ErrorNotification.css

```
.error-notification {
  font-weight: bold;
  border-left: 10px solid #9a2c30;
  background-color: #cb454b;
  color: #ffffff;

  & .error-notification-message {
    margin: 0px;
  }

  & .accordion-container {
    padding: 10px;

    & .accordion-top-section {
      display: flex;
      justify-content: center;
      width: 100%;

      & .accordion-button {
        width: 100%;
      }
    }

    & .accordion-panel {
      max-height: 0;
      overflow: hidden;
      transition: max-height 0.2s ease-in;
    }

    & .collapsed {
      & .accordion-panel {
        max-height: 100px;
        overflow: hidden;
        transition: max-height 0.2s ease-out;
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: That's not vanilla css, are you sure your sass is being preprocessed and converted to vanilla css?

Comment: I see `error-notification-container` but I don't see `error-notification` in your html?

Comment: @SuperDJ thats because I'm using react toastify to render error notification component which has the className attached to that. code looks like this: 
`export const renderErrorNotification = details => {
  toast.error(<ErrorNotification details={details} />, {className: cx('error-notification')}) }` so it binds the className once it's rendered.

Comment: @Ted yes sass is preprocessing it and it catches the other rules. the only rule not being processed is `.collapsed` class rule.

Comment: Is the output what you expected it to be? https://www.sassmeister.com/gist/a41313db236a8e7edbb9e9748117e61b. Shouldn't the selector be `.accordion-container.collapsed .accordion-panel`?

Comment: @Ted in this case all @ Ben needs to do is to remove the space between the ampersand and `.collapsed` so `&.collapsed` instead of `& .collapsed`

Comment: Yeah I just realized I was wrong about that and deleted my comment

Comment: @Ted removing the space worked! thank you for the help!

Comment: That was @SuperDJ , not me :)

Comment: @Ben if a answer helped you, you should mark it as the answer. This will help others as well

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is this rule:

```
& .collapsed {
```

It makes the output:

```
.error-notification .accordion-container .collapsed
```

While what you want is:

```
.error-notification .accordion-container.collapsed
```

You can achieve this result by removing the space:

```
&.collapsed {
```

You can check this here: https://www.sassmeister.com/gist/a41313db236a8e7edbb9e9748117e61b

Answer (score 2):

The problem is that you are using wrong selector

```
.accordion-container {
  & .collapsed {
  }
}
```

Your selector means: select all elements with `.collapsed` class inside element with `.accordion-container` class and looks like this in pure css

```
.accordion-container .collapsed {
}
```

But you want to select exactly `.accordion-container` with class `.collapsed` on the same element, so,
for this you should use this selector

```
.accordion-container.collapsed
```

Or according to your code

```
&.collapsed
```

Summary: **No space between & and .collapsed**

Answer (score 1):

Remove the space between `&` and `.collapsed`.

Edit: Actually you can just simplify that selector since the nesting is unnecessary.

```
.error-notification {
  font-weight: bold;
  border-left: 10px solid #9a2c30;
  background-color: #cb454b;
  color: #ffffff;

  & .error-notification-message {
    margin: 0px;
  }

  & .accordion-container {
    padding: 10px;

    & .accordion-top-section {
      display: flex;
      justify-content: center;
      width: 100%;

      & .accordion-button {
        width: 100%;
      }
    }

    & .accordion-panel {
      max-height: 0;
      overflow: hidden;
      transition: max-height 0.2s ease-in;
    }

    &.collapsed .accordion-panel {
      max-height: 100px;
      overflow: hidden;
      transition: max-height 0.2s ease-out;
    }
  }
}
```

In SASS, if you do this:

```
.parent {
  & .someClass {}
}
```

It will select `.someClass` *children* of `.parent`. If you want it to select `.parent` classes that *also* have the `.someClass` class, it needs to be like this:

```
.parent {
  &.someClass {}
}
```